# Does a state which is passed at least 3 times had to be passed 5 times in Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

> Prove of disprove: Let $\{X_n\}_n$ be homogenous Markov chain. if we start from state $i$, there is a positive probability that we pass at least 3 times at state $j$. Does it follows that exists positive probability s.t if we start in state $i$, we pass at state $j$ at least 5 times?

That seems correct but I can't explain it formally. How can I prove it ?

Comment: Hint: For every positive $k$, $P_i(N_j\geqslant k)=P_i(T_j\lt\infty)P_j(T_j\lt\infty)^{k-1}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $N_j,T_j$?

Comment: Near universal notations in the domain: T for hitting times, N for number of visits. Do they not use these in the textbook/lectures you are following?

Comment: I started using Peres's book about mixing times in chains yesterday and they used it there. thanks. However, suppose I substitute $k=5$ I get an upper bounding for $P_i(N_j\ge 5)$ but not a lower bound as the question required.

Comment: Sorry but what are you talking about? My comment has an equal sign, not an inequality sign.

Comment: My mistake. I figured it out only now. thanks again.